# Bootstrap navbar-toggle is not working, does not expand with menu items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So Im not sure what is going on with my bootstrap navbar because I cant seem to get the toggle button to show my menu items. I've looked at similar question answers which suggest loading jquery before bootstrap script, which I did and it still doesnt work. 
Heres my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border-radius: 0;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed burger-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cutom-bs-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand jura-font" href="/#!/">COLIGN</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Account</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Invite a friend</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="/auth/signout">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form text-center" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group nav-search-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control nav-search-input" placeholder="search for patents and research...">
                        </div>
                        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have typo in data-target. it must be

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed burger-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-bs-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
```

Comment: this didnt fix the problem